# Capistrano Not recognizing secret_key_base in Rails production.enc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, credentials, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using Capistrano to deploy my Rails 7.0.2 app with Ruby 3.1.1, when I run `cap production deploy`  and then when Capistrano runs:

```
deploy:assets:precompile
$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I receive the following error :

```
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`
```

deploy.rb:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock '~> 3.17.0'

set :application, 'app'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:foo/app.git'

# Deploy to the user's home directory
set :deploy_to, "/#{fetch :application}"

append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

# Only keep the last 5 re
```

The problem is that I already have the secret_key_base defined in my productions encrypted credentials file so I should not be getting this error. I also tried putting the secret_key_base as a .rbenv-vars file and still got the same error. How do I properly use a secret_key_base in a production environment with Rails and Capistrano? Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Can you try adding to the deploy.rb file:

`append :linked_files,  'config/credentials/production.key',`

And copy the production.key (the one that is in charge of decrypting the production credentials) to the shared folder in your server, something like `/var/www/{proyect_name}/shared/config/credentials/production.key` you can leave the production.yml.enc in your GitHub.

And check that you have set the secret_key_base in your production secret keys with EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit -e production

Comment: Brilliant, this worked for me. This has been driving me crazy for several hours, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this solution! So much time spent on such an easy fix. Wish I found it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Added the following to `config/environments/production`:

`config.require_master_key = true`

run `EDITOR=vi rails credentials:edit --environment=production`
Save the production key generated to your server @ `app/config/credentials/production.key`

Changed `set :deploy_to, "/#{fetch :application}"` to `set :deploy_to, "~/#{fetch :application}"`

Comment: secret_key_base should be placed in the config/credentials/production.yml.enc file !